# what is Alternative of android.enableD8=false because it is deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

Hello I am using okio and okhttp library for socket connect.
After updating android studio and build tool 3.1.2, I am facing this [issue.](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/325)

And suggestion is **android.enableD8=false.** but, it's deprecated.

So, Please Suggest What I need to do for solving this issue?

Comment: so you are getting array OutofBoundException for using deprecated methods?

Comment: No, If I don't Write **android.enableD8=false** in gradle properties, then I get  array OutofBoundException.

Comment: the link that you have mentioned already says there is a bug in it and only work if you write that line or else the app will crash.

Comment: but, is it due to gradle update or library issue?

Comment: It is due to library issue.

Answer (score 4):

read this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-switching-to-d8-dexer.html

then go to

> gradle.properties

and Use 'android.enableD8=true' to remove this warning.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this you have only one option that is using `android.enableD8=false`.And as it is deprecated not removed.Hence,you can use it without any problem.

Also keep an eye on the [LINK](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/325) for update about the fix.